# Unable to use whitelisted https sources in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, https, google-chrome-extension

Why can't I use https whitelisted google JSAPI to create a custom search engine in the popup window?

I get the content policy violation.

my manifest looks like this:

```
  "content_security_policy": "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js https://www.google.co.uk/jsapi; object-src 'self'",
```

Comment: Revert to manifest v.1. In manifest file add `manifest_version: 1`.

Comment: but it is soon going to be unsupported and i want to keep the development time low and stick to the latest norms. There must be a way of doing this but I just cant figure one out. If you know any please help.

Comment: The docs clearly states: There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes `unsafe-inline` will have no effect. This is intentional.

Comment: "default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; for the inline css. not for js.